# do linux containers go to sleep?

Tags: linux, ssh, containers, lxc, sshd

I keep receiving randomly "refused connection" while trying to ssh into linux containers.

In order to try to find if it was a rogue computer that was impersonating the IP of the container, I ran an arping on the interface of the machine what was trying to reach the container and inside the container, but there's no duplicate IPs.

I double checked the SSH configuration of the container and on the "hypervisor" host to make sure that it wasn't a timeout or something.

The current solution that I found is to keep a crontab SSHing into the container and in that way I stopped receiving the "refused connection" error.

So I started to wonder: Does anybody knows if containers go to sleep when they're inactive?

Thank you, very much in advance for your kind answers!

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

No, not at all.
One thing you must realise is that processes running inside a container are similar to any other process running on the kernel. The kernel does see any difference between them, apart from the fact that it has different namespaces and cgroups to limit the resource usage.
If you using docker, you can easily find the PID of any container by running the following command

```
docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' container_name
```